# size of derived class object in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class base
{
};

class der_1:public base
{
};

class der_2:virtual public base
{
};

int main()
{
    der_1 a;  //size of a is 1
    der_2 b;  //size of b is 4  ?? why
    cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

object b internally contains virtual pointer, so its size is 4 instead of 1(like a).
But what this virtual pointer is  pointing to ?

Answer (score 6):

This is purely implementation dependent. It depends on how an implementation implements dynamic dispatch/virtualism. And this is the reason C++ standard library provides `sizeof` to get the actual size so that you don't have to guesstimate/estimate it. Always use it instead of making any assumptions on the size.

However most implementations(*read all*) use the virtual table and pointer mechanism to achieve this and the additional 4 bytes size you see is for the vptr bookkeeping.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably pointing to the virtual function table for the class. This is necessary, in most implementations, to allow things like `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: but class der_2 donot have any virtual function. so how its virtual table is possible ?

Comment: @AdityaSharma - It has virtual inheritance. That's enough (more than enough!) to trigger the need for a viable. Besides, it's a bad idea to inherit from a base class that does not have a virtual destructor. The compiler emits code assuming that core principles are being followed. There's no reason for a compiler to have special size-reducing handling for classes that inherit virtually from base classes that have no virtual methods. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The size of pointers will vary between machines. For example on my machine, it is `8`.

[Size of the classes in case of virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541149/size-of-the-classes-in-case-of-virtual-inheritance)

> Whenever you have virtual inheritance, the location of the virtual
>   base subobject with respect to the start of the complete type is
>   unknown, so an extra pointer is added to the original object to track
>   where the virtual base is.

[Does virtual inheritance increase the size of derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043099/does-virtual-inheritance-increase-the-size-of-derived-class)

> This behavior is **completely implementation-specific** and there are no
>   guarantees about what will happen. That said, most compilers implement
>   virtual inheritance by having a single copy of the base class lying
>   around, then having each instance of the derived class store a pointer
>   inside its class body that points to that one unique instance. That
>   way, if you cast the object to its virtual base, the compiler can emit
>   code to find out where that object is. On a 32-bit system, this means
>   that virtual inheritance might increase the size of the object by four
>   bytes, as you've observed.